# making div invisible and after clicking link make it visible

Tags: html, css

I have two different div's I want to make one of them invisible and after clicking the link or button I want it to be visible and the other invisible. I don't know javascript so I know only HTML and CSS. Can I do that with only using HTML&CSS and How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: How are the DIVs related to each other? Show some of your HTML.

Comment: Please provide some code for us to look at, otherwise we may just tell you things you've already tried.

Comment: No, it's not possible with html/css only

Comment: If you don't know js, try jquery and refer to examples here - http://api.jquery.com/css As you already know CSS, visibility is required to be set hidden on button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jQuery for this.
Just add this line to your head tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
```

If your HTML is like this:

```
<div id="div1">This is div1</div>
<div id="div2">This is div2</div>
<button id="button1">Toggle divs</button>
```

CSS:

```
#div2 {
    display:none;
}
```

At the bottom of your page, just before the closing tag `</body>` add the following JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $("#button1").on("click", function () {
        $("#div1, #div2").toggle();
    }
</script>
```

Here's a link for a similar example:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#entry-examples